# Alternative storage for SVN backup with rsync

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, amazon-s3, joyent

I've been backing up my SVN repo and trac environment using a weekly cron job and 2 custom scripts. This has been going to Joyent Strongspace; but since they have discontinued the service, I need an alternative provider. I would prefer amazon S3 because I already use it, but any alternative that will work without too much (any) changes to my process will be welcome.

Here are my 2 scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -rltpvz --delete /svn/ kryptonite\@mycompany.joyent.net@strongspace.joyent.net:svn

#!/bin/sh
rsync -rltpvz --delete /var/lib/trac/ kryptonite\@mycompany.joyent.net@strongspace.joyent.net:trac
```

Comment: Really, no one knows? How do other people backup their SCM server?

Answer (score 1):

S3 doesn't support rsync out of the box. However, you can use FUSE and [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) to create a file system over S3 and then rsync there.

From there, you can follow [this guide](http://blog.eberly.org/2008/10/27/how-i-automated-my-backups-to-amazon-s3-using-rsync/) on setting up the whole thing.